# Using CALayers from UIViews to mask, but using the inverted layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I have something setup similar to this:

```
self.mainView.layer.mask = self.maskingView.layer
```

And I want to have another view like this, but with the mask inverted:

```
self.otherView.layer.mask = self.otherMaskingView.layer
```

I know that you can do something like this without using `UIView`, but I would like to use it because I can just update `maskingView.frame` and the mask will be updated.

How can I invert the mask of `self.otherMaskingView.layer` so that the mask that is applied is inverted?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder what your problem is?

Comment: @KudoCC How do I invert the mask of the second view's layer?